# combineLatest reset observable - Rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 4 observables inside "combineLatest". What I need is that if observables 1, 3 or 4 emit a value, observable 2 resets its value. It's possible? Thank you

1. Mat-table sort change event (Sort class)
2. Mat-table change page event (PageEvent class)
3. Custom observable (filter)
4. Custom observable (other filter)

```
combineLatest($1, $2, $3, $4).subscribe(([a, b, c, d]) => CALL_HTTP_WITH_PARAMETERS(a, b, c, d))
```

Example (first values)

```
$1 = name,asc
$2 = 2
$3 = bla bla
$4 = bla bla

CALL_HTTP_WITH_PARAMETERS("name,asc", 2, "bla bla", "bla bla")
```

Observable 1 emit "name,desc" value

```
$1 = name,desc
$2 = 2 ==> has to be 1 again
$3 = bla bla
$4 = bla bla

CALL_HTTP_WITH_PARAMETERS("name,desc", 1, "bla bla", "bla bla")
```

Other

Observable 3 emit "new value" value

```
$1 = name,asc
$2 = 2 ==> has to be 1 again
$3 = new value
$4 = bla bla

CALL_HTTP_WITH_PARAMETERS("name,asc", 1, "new value", "bla bla")
```

Comment: Maybe you can create observable 2 as a `merge` between the original observable 2 source and observable 1,3,4 merge and map to `reset` initial value.

Comment: What do you mean by reset?

Comment: @martin "Observable 2" contains the current page shown in the table (PageEvent class), what I need is that if the observables 1, 3 or 4 emit a new value, the value of observable 2, has to be 1 again keeping the value of the other observables and thus, make the HTTP request with the updated data.

Comment: @elpddev Thanks for the answer, but can you give me an example, I got lost among so many "merges"

Comment: @avechuche Its something along the lines of `$bNew = merge($bOrig, merge(a$, c$).pipe(map(() => someInitValue))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can,
Consider below strategy

Assume we have the `Observables` `$a`, `$b`, `$c` and `$d`, we will define these as `Subjects`.

We would like `$a`, `$c` and `$d` to reset `$b`. We can pipe these`Observables` to reset `$b`

```typescript
const $aSubject = new Subject()
const $bSubject = new Subject()
const $cSubject = new Subject()
const $dSubject = new Subject()
const $a = $aSubject.asObservable().pipe(
  tap(() => $bSubject.next(0))
)
const $b = $bSubject.asObservable()
const $c = $cSubject.asObservable().pipe(
  tap(() => $bSubject.next(0))
)
const $d = $dSubject.asObservable().pipe(
  tap(() => $bSubject.next(0))
)
```

Now we have managed to update `$b` on changes of the rest of the variables. Unfortunately this causes an infinite loop, as `$b` will always emit in the `combineLatest()` function. To solve this, we will pipe these `Observable` to the `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

The next problem to solve is extra httpCalls. Consider a situation where we change the first parameter which consequently updates the value of the second parameter. This will make 2 calls. We only need 1 call so we will use `switchMap` operator to cancel any earlier requests

```typescript
combineLatest([$1, $2, $3, $4]).pipe(
  switchMap(([a, b, c, d])=> callHttp(a, b, c, d))
)
```

[See this simple demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jpdkkn?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reset the observable.

Think about what the observable is watching and change it.

For example:

```
merge($1, $3, $4).pipe(
   tap(_=> this.myGrid.setPage(1))
).subscribe()
```

Or, if it's out of your control, create `Subject` and use `next`.

For example:

```
subject2 = new Subject<number>();
$2 = this.subject2.asObservable();
onPageChanged(pageNumber:number){
   this.subject2.next(pageNumber);
}

merge($1, $3, $4).pipe(
   tap(_=> this.subject2.next(1))
).subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't understand how "merge" would help me. If observable 1 outputs a value, I don't have access to the value of observable 3 or 4 (inside the merge) and I need that, that's why I use combineLastest. See my examples.

Comment: I meant for you to do it in addition to combineLatest and not instead.